# Importing XML into SQL using Linq to XML, is there a more efficient way?

Tags: web-services, import, linq-to-xml

I have XML that I need to put in a SQL database. I am using LINQ to XML get the data I want out of the XML.

It seems to me that I waste a lot of time by mapping variables with Linq to XML and then saving those variables. I am wondering if I can combine these steps.

This is an example query. I perform this one many times and other ones on similar data.

Maybe somehow make the LINQ to XML create my LINQ objects directly instead of LINQ creating its own objects behind the scenes.

Here's my code.

```
        HttpWebRequest request2 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(newURI);
        request2.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        request2.PreAuthenticate = true;
        request2.Credentials = credentialCache;
        request2.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;
        request2.Method = "GET";

        HttpWebResponse response2 = null;
        try
        {
            response2 = (HttpWebResponse)request2.GetResponse();
            HttpStatusCode statusCode2 = response2.StatusCode;

            using (Stream responseData2 = response2.GetResponseStream())
            {
                // TODO: Handle HTTP status code and response data here

                XDocument userInfo = XDocument.Load(responseData2);
                XNamespace userInfoNamespace = "http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/data";
                XNamespace dmdNamespace = "http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/data-metadata";

                var Records = from Record in userInfo.Descendants(userInfoNamespace + "Record")
                              select new
                              {
                                  college = Record.Element(dmdNamespace + "IndexEntry").Attribute("entryKey").Value,
                                  department = Record.Element(dmdNamespace + "IndexEntry").ElementsAfterSelf(dmdNamespace + "IndexEntry").FirstOrDefault().IsEmpty ? Record.Element(dmdNamespace + "IndexEntry").ElementsAfterSelf(dmdNamespace + "IndexEntry").FirstOrDefault().Attribute("entryKey").Value : "blank",
                                  prefix = (string)Record.Descendants(userInfoNamespace + "PREFIX").SingleOrDefault(),
                                  fname = (string)Record.Descendants(userInfoNamespace + "FNAME").SingleOrDefault(),
                                  pfname = (string)Record.Descendants(userInfoNamespace + "PFNAME").SingleOrDefault(),
                                  mname = (string)Record.Descendants(userInfoNamespace + "MNAME").SingleOrDefault(),
                                  lname = (string)Record.Descendants(userInfoNamespace + "LNAME").SingleOrDefault(),
                                  suffix = (string)Record.Descendants(userInfoNamespace + "SUFFIX").SingleOrDefault(),
                                  alt_name = (string)Record.Descendants(userInfoNamespace + "ALT_NAME").SingleOrDefault(),
                                  endpos = (string)Record.Descendants(userInfoNamespace + "ENDPOS").SingleOrDefault(),
                                  email = (string)Record.Descendants(userInfoNamespace + "EMAIL").SingleOrDefault(),
                                  building = (string)Record.Descendants(userInfoNamespace + "BUILDING").SingleOrDefault(),
                                  ophone1 = (string)Record.Descendants(userInfoNamespace + "OPHONE1").SingleOrDefault(),
                                  ophone2 = (string)Record.Descendants(userInfoNamespace + "OPHONE2").SingleOrDefault(),
                                  ophone3 = (string)Record.Descendants(userInfoNamespace + "OPHONE3").SingleOrDefault(),
                                  dphone1 = (string)Record.Descendants(userInfoNamespace + "DPHONE1").SingleOrDefault(),
                                  dphone2 = (string)Record.Descendants(userInfoNamespace + "DPHONE2").SingleOrDefault(),
                                  dphone3 = (string)Record.Descendants(userInfoNamespace + "DPHONE3").SingleOrDefault(),
                                  fax1 = (string)Record.Descendants(userInfoNamespace + "FAX1").SingleOrDefault(),
                                  fax2 = (string)Record.Descendants(userInfoNamespace + "FAX2").SingleOrDefault(),
                                  fax3 = (string)Record.Descendants(userInfoNamespace + "FAX3").SingleOrDefault(),
                                  website = (string)Record.Descendants(userInfoNamespace + "WEBSITE").SingleOrDefault(),
                                  gender = (string)Record.Descendants(userInfoNamespace + "GENDER").SingleOrDefault(),
                                  ethnicity = (string)Record.Descendants(userInfoNamespace + "ETHNICITY").SingleOrDefault(),
                                  citizen = (string)Record.Descendants(userInfoNamespace + "CITIZEN").SingleOrDefault(),
                                  bio = (string)Record.Descendants(userInfoNamespace + "BIO").SingleOrDefault(),
                                  teaching_interests = (string)Record.Descendants(userInfoNamespace + "TEACHING_INTERESTS").SingleOrDefault(),
                                  research_interests = (string)Record.Descendants(userInfoNamespace + "RESEARCHINTERETS").SingleOrDefault(),
                                  expertise = (string)Record.Descendants(userInfoNamespace + "EXPERTISE").SingleOrDefault(),
                                  upload_photo = (string)Record.Descendants(userInfoNamespace + "UPLOAD_PHOTO").SingleOrDefault(),
                                  upload_cv = (string)Record.Descendants(userInfoNamespace + "UPLOAD_CV").SingleOrDefault(),
                              };

                foreach (var recordItem in Records)
                {
                    PCI a = new PCI();
                    a.COLLEGE = recordItem.college;
                    a.DEPARTMENT = recordItem.department;
                    a.PREFIX = recordItem.prefix;
                    a.FNAME = recordItem.fname;
                    a.PFNAME = recordItem.pfname;
                    a.MNAME = recordItem.mname;
                    a.LNAME = recordItem.lname;
                    a.SUFFIX = recordItem.suffix;
                    a.ALT_NAME = recordItem.alt_name;
                    a.ENDPOS = recordItem.endpos;
                    a.EMAIL = recordItem.email;
                    a.BUILDING = recordItem.building;
                    a.OPHONE1 = recordItem.ophone1;
                    a.OPHONE2 = recordItem.ophone2;
                    a.OPHONE3 = recordItem.ophone3;
                    a.DPHONE1 = recordItem.dphone1;
                    a.DPHONE2 = recordItem.dphone2;
                    a.DPHONE3 = recordItem.dphone3;
                    a.FAX1 = recordItem.fax1;
                    a.FAX2 = recordItem.fax2;
                    a.FAX3 = recordItem.fax3;
                    a.WEBSITE = recordItem.website;
                    a.GENDER = recordItem.gender;
                    a.ETHNICITY = recordItem.citizen;
                    a.CITIZEN = recordItem.citizen;
                    a.BIO = recordItem.bio;
                    a.TEACHING_INTERESTS = recordItem.teaching_interests;
                    a.RESEARCH_INTERESTS = recordItem.research_interests;
                    a.EXPERTISE = recordItem.expertise;
                    a.UPLOAD_PHOTO = recordItem.upload_photo;
                    a.UPLOAD_CV = recordItem.upload_cv;

                    faimdc.PCIs.InsertOnSubmit(a);
                    faimdc.SubmitChanges();
                }
          }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of projecting to an anonymous type you can create the PCI class directly and you would not have to copy everything. Something like:

```
var Records = from Record in userInfo.Descendants(userInfoNamespace + "Record")
              select new PCI
              {
                  COLLEGE = Record.Element(dmdNamespace + "IndexEntry").Attribute("entryKey").Value,
                  DEPARTMENT =  Record.Element(dmdNamespace + "IndexEntry").ElementsAfterSelf(dmdNamespace + "IndexEntry").FirstOrDefault().IsEmpty ? Record.Element(dmdNamespace + "IndexEntry").ElementsAfterSelf(dmdNamespace + "IndexEntry").FirstOrDefault().Attribute("entryKey").Value : "blank",
                  …
              }
```

You probably also want the submit to be called once and outside the loop rather than in the loop.